# password protection on and off

Tags: android

i have an issue regarding login page,for example an apps installed in mobile.starting page is signup page,in this page user select password protection on,apps strat from login page,if user select password protection off ,then apps strat from meu page..
which mean signup page should come only once installed in mobile.
here apps strat from signup page only,so if we open second time,the apps will strat based on password protection options.
if we delete the apps from mobile ,and install again then the apps should astart from signup page
do you have any idea how to set intent-filter
is it possible to set condition for intent filter?
please suggest me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the app from your device then all your SharedPreferences, databases etc are removed as well. That means that your app automatically starts from the Login page (since the login information is deleted)

Comment: but problem in password protection options.how can i set funtionality for tht